# Join with 2 cols ids

Tags: mysql, sql

Well I have following tables:

TableA

```
from_no  | to_no    | msg    
43288519 | 59215348 | hi    
43288519 | 123456   | hello    
59215348 | 43288519 | how are you.
```

TableB

```
contactno | Name    
43288519  | Priyam    
123456    | ADC   
59215348  | Ankur
```

Result I am looking for is:

```
from   | to     | msg    
Priyam | Ankur  | hi    
Priyam | adc    | hello   
Ankur  | Priyam | How are you
```

Please share the SQL Statement for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed with @Prdp.

One more way, Assuming `contactno` is unique, is:

```
select
    (select name from tableb where contactono = t.from_no),
    (select name from tableb where contactono = t.to_no),
    msg
from
    tablea t;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to Join `TableB` twice

```
select B1.Name as from, B2.Name as to, a.Msg 
from TableA A 
join TableB B1 on A.from_no  = B1.contactno 
join TableB B2 on A.to_no = B2.contactno
```

Considering there wont be any `NULL` values in `from_no` & `to_no` columns of `TableA`.